# How can I read and write XML documents in OMNeT++?

Tags: xml, omnet++

I would like to use XML files to process data in my OMNeT++ simulations. After reading the manual, I've figured out how to read XML files with the OMNeT++ API. However, when I trying write something into the XML file, this doesn't work. The following code fragment illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```
cXMLElement *xmlPosture;
xmlPosture = par("traceFile").xmlValue();
cXMLElementList Entities = xmlPostureW->getElementsByTagName("Entity");
(*Entities[0]).setAttribute("X_Position", "100");
(*Entities[0]).setAttribute("Y_Position", "100");
(*Entities[0]).setAttribute("Z_Position", "100");
```

The resulting XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <Entity id="0" X_Position="250" Y_Position="250" Z_Position="0" Speed="0.1">
    </Entity>
    <Entity id="1" X_Position="250" Y_Position="300" Z_Position="0" Speed="0.1">
    </Entity>
    <Entity id="2" X_Position="250" Y_Position="200" Z_Position="0" Speed="0.1">
    </Entity>
    <Entity id="3" X_Position="200" Y_Position="250" Z_Position="0" Speed="0.1">
    </Entity>
    <Entity id="4" X_Position="100" Y_Position="250" Z_Position="0" Speed="0.1">
    </Entity>
    <Entity id="5" X_Position="150" Y_Position="220" Z_Position="0" Speed="0.1">
    </Entity>
</root>
```

For some reason, I'm not seeing the changes that I'm writing into the file (see the code fragment above). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What I want to do is to modify the xml file like the attributes above in xml sample doc. As I using the setAttribute function , but it didn`t work which confused me. Can anyone give me some advice ?

Comment: Don't just say it didn't work, or that something goes wrong - you need to explicitly state the problem you are experiencing and everything you can share about the problem.

Comment: Sorry about that, but the code has no errors, no warnings. Just open the file ,get the element, set attributes. But, when I run after the code ,the original xml file does not change.Is there anything else I haven`t said before ? I`m the fresh, sorry about the express.And thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not actually changing the file, you're just modifying the internal representation of the XML document. You should actually write that to disk.

If I understand the context of your question correctly, you're trying to generate a trace file that you can later analyze with other tools in an XML format. If that's the case, you should probably write your XML file to disk in your OMNeT++ modules' `finish` method. The problem is that you're using the OMNeT++ cXML* classes to open your file: these are intended for configuration purposes only, and thus they are read only (see e.g., [this entry in the API documentation](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cXMLElement.html)).

Thus, I recommend that you either include a library that can do XML writing, or switch to a simpler format such as CSV or JSON (I personally use [rapidJSON](http://rapidjson.org/) to export to a JSON format, but that may not work for you). You could also try to use OMNeT++'s statistics framework to export data, but it isn't really designed for arbitrary output, such as message logs.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I cannot agree more with you after debugging my program that I just modified the internal XML document without write it back to disk. Besides, the link is very useful.